# How to access Items from ListBox? - WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My problem is that I can't access the properties of the **UserСontrol** created in the **ListBox**.

I have an empty **ListBox** to which I add a **UserСontrol** by clicking a button.

```
private void addButtton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SignalButton signalButton = new SignalButton(); // Initialization UserControl
    signalButton.Width = 200;
    signalButton.Height = 45;
    mainListBox.Items.Insert(0, signalButton);
}
```

How do I access the **UserСontrol** properties located in the **ListBox**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access to the added `UserControl`, you need to keep track of them in a `List<UserControl> _useControlList;` outside the `ListBox`, and access to one, for instance, the last one by `_useControlList.Last()`, and then access to its properties.

But then you are not separating design and its logic, which can be a problem (maintenance, testability, flexibility, understandability etc).

I have a feeling that you are not separating design and logic (like in MVVM), which will make your project super messy and hard to maintain and understand. For that I recommend that you define a `UserControl` as a View, with its design defined in the XAML, and associate a ViewModel, where you put the View logic. Then your ListBox/ListView will use a DataTemplate.

Example:

View (extract):

```
<ListView Background="Transparent" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MidiCLPCollection}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMidiCLPVM}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MidiCLPViewModel}">
            <local:MidiCLPView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel (extract):

```
public ObservableCollection<MidiCLPViewModel> MidiCLPCollection
    { get; protected set; } = new();
```

and `MidiCLPView` is your UserControl (.xaml + .xaml.cs).